# Background fading out on both side (pure html)

Tags: html, css, background-color, fadeout

I have a first name and last name in a red background color and would like that red color to fadeout on the left and right (approximately at 2/10 and 8/10 of the red background), using css.

Any help welcome, please

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
color: white;
text-align: center;
background-image: 
url(https://www.abercrombiekent.com/-/media/ak/media-for-prod/journeys/lsgj/asia-classic-japan-mt-fuji-cherry-blossom-mh.jpg?h=500&w=1224&la=en&hash=FE20C6C6D4D6D693DD79CAA29352D7F9825D6804)
}

.name{
background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.8);
}

.img{
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
width: 100%;
background-attachment: fixed;
align-items: center;
}

h1{
margin-top: -10px;
font-size: 80px;
letter-spacing: 8px;
font-family: Arial;
}

h2{
margin-top: -60px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
font-size: 31px;
letter-spacing: 5px;
font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<div class= "img">
<div class= "name">
<h1>/////</h1>
<h2>///////////</h2>
</div></div>
```

Comment: can you be more precise

Comment: I pretty much want that same effect on both side: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/00/Kleurenovergang_van_wit_naar_rood.png
Assuming the width to be 100px, I would like it to start fading on the left at 20px and on the right at 80px

Comment: this is called gradient .. so do a search about gradient

Answer (score 0):

The background gradient can be set using `background: linear-gradient`. You can put in as many stops as you like using a percentage to indicate the position and  rgba colors which allow you to modify opacity.

I changed your background color to this gradient:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 10%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 20%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 80%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 90%);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(https://www.abercrombiekent.com/-/media/ak/media-for-prod/journeys/lsgj/asia-classic-japan-mt-fuji-cherry-blossom-mh.jpg?h=500&w=1224&la=en&hash=FE20C6C6D4D6D693DD79CAA29352D7F9825D6804)
}

.name {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 10%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 20%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 80%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 90%);
}

.img {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: -10px;
  font-size: 80px;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: -60px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 31px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <div class="name">
    <h1>/////</h1>
    <h2>///////////</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```